# Issue with xNeat Clipboard Manager & Sublime Text 3 / Editing default key-bindings in Windows 7

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to switch to using Sublime Text 3 as my API, due in no small part to its multitude of keyboard shortcuts.

However, I have encountered a serious problem. I have xNeat Clipboard Manager installed which has the key-binding crtl+shift+v (also tied to a custom mouse button) which brings up my 20 last copied strings. It's a little tool I absolutely love for coding and I'm not about to give it up. However, it doesn't work on ST3, presumably due to a conflict. Opening the Default Keybindings list within ST3 states that this combination is already reserved for "paste_and_indent". I'd be quite happy to just delete this, but there doesn't seem to be any options given within the program, and I can't find the file on my computer (The path to the sublime-keymap file doesn't seem to exist- not even with showing all hidden files?)

Can anyone guide me as to how I can delete this keybinding please. I'm using Windows 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having the same issue with xNeat Clipboard manager or similar, my solution was this:

Install [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) instead. It operates in a very similar way to xNeat and you can tie it to the same keybinding. And most importantly... it seems to work in ST3. Don't forget to also remove the ctrl+shift+v keybinding from ST3 defaults to avoid a conflict, or else pick a different combination.

Comment: Thank you, for others you can do it:

In Preferences -> key Bindings Default set:

{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+v"], "command": false } or just remove
 ["ctrl+shift+v"] line at all

then in Ditto set this shortcut

Comment: No problem- Glad this has helped someone!

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime Text 3, just click

> Key Bindings - Default

in the `Preferences` menu, and it should open the keymap file in the editor.

Edit: on my system, for some reason the folder `%AppData%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default` didn't exist and pressing Ctrl+S on the keymap file returned an error (unable to save), however after manually creating the "Default" directory the keymap file got saved there and it seems to work now.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but unless I'm missing something, you can't edit this file within ST3- you can only view it?

Comment: @Inigo I tried that and indeed I couldn't save it, however after creating the missing "Default" directory it worked, see my updated answer.

Comment: Great, thank you. I can edit & save now. (Weird.. where is this file loading from initially?) Unfortunately though this hasn't completely fixed my problem as xNeat is still not working with ST3...

Comment: @Inigo the editor maybe didn't reload the file, try closing it completely and eventually killing its process using the Task Manager, then try again.

Comment: Thanks Andre, definitely some other problem though. I see here someone has the same issue: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=40400 A year ago but no response. Very annoying for me.

Comment: @Inigo take a look at [this](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13303), someone suggests editing the default "package" using [this](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) tool, however when trying to edit the keymap file in the default package it points me to the exact same path where the keymap file got extracted when clicking on "Key Bindings - Default"...

Comment: Hmmm. Tried swapping/overwriting keybindings, to no avail. It does seem as if ST3 essentially arrogates total jurisdiction of your keyboard. Nevermind. Thanks anyway. +1 for solving the filepath problem.

Comment: @Inigo thanks for the +1; try asking on their [technical support](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3) forum.